# Why gravitational waves are not part of thermal phenomena?

Tags: electromagnetism, gravity, thermal-radiation, gravitational-waves

Electromagnetic waves are part of thermal phenomena in the form of thermal radiations.

But why gravitational waves do not show up as a thermal phenomenon, for example, why gravitational waves do not (directly) contribute to the making of temperature?

And if there are gravitons, what gravitons have to be to avoid being part of thermal phenomena?

Comment: What makes you think they aren't?

Comment: I can't find any known thermal phenomena that can be attributed to gravitational wave. And if gravitational waves are thermal, they should dominate the background temperature in the universe but that is not the case.

Comment: Gravitational waves are very, very weak in comparison to other contributions under any but the most extreme circumstances.  Detecting gravitational waves is only barely in our grasp now, but we've known about the much more obvious forms of energy for a long time.  Size matters, at least when you're trying to measure it. :-)

Comment: Then the gravitational wave being so weak is in itself a problem. How can a very strong and long range gravitational force having such a weak gravitational wave? 
Where exactly the does gravitational force come from?